# BackgroundWorker Functioning Properly

Tags: c#

I recently attempted to thread a foreach loop because it was freezing the UI when it ran. This loop looks through a bunch of log files and retrieves information from them line by line, then adds it to a listView(also prints something to a richtextBox). The issue I'm having is that after threading this loop, it seems that neither the listView nor the richTextBox update anymore. I know for a fact that the method is being called, because when I put a MessageBox after that 'if statement', it opens just fine but everything else refuses to work.

```
public void searchForAll(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (//argument)
        {
            listViewEx1.Items.Clear();
            int logcount = 0;
            richTextBoxEx1.Text += "Print something";
            richTextBoxEx1.Text += "\n";
            richTextBoxEx1.SelectionStart = richTextBoxEx1.Text.Length;
            richTextBoxEx1.ScrollToCaret();
            foreach (User user in s.Friends)
            {
                foreach (string log in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.log"))
                {
                    string[] fileToRead = File.ReadAllLines(log);
                    foreach (string line in fileToRead)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains(user.Handle) && line.Contains("-r"))
                        {

                            if (!isDuplicate(c))
                            {
                                listViewEx1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(user.Handle)
                                {
                                    SubItems = { c }
                                });
                                dupCheck.Add(c);
                                logcount++;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
                dupCheck.Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            richTextBoxEx1.Text += "Print something";
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: I think here a good matches for using of `async/await`. `async/await` was designed for working with `Input/Output` operations in little bid more friendly way then threading or `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: Hi, Fabio! I just switched to async/await. The thing is that puts me back to square one. Using async/await freezes the GUI, but updates the listview and richtextbox

Comment: I'm also getting a warning saying that the async method lacks await operators

Comment: Show your `async/await` code. And _Using async/await freezes the GUI, but updates the listview and richtextbox_ - sounds like nonsense, if GUI thread freezes then controls will not be updated

Comment: You should not be accessing UI elements from a thread other than the UI thread that owns those elements. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what you need to fix. But based on the little bit of code you posted and your problem description, I suspect that you are starting the background thread before the form is fully initialized, causing the elements like `richTextBoxEx1` to be owned by the background thread instead of the UI thread, so that even though you're not blocking the UI thread any longer, those controls don't work.

Comment: Were you to wait for the controls to be fully initialized before you started the background thread, you'd get an `InvalidOperationException` with a cross-thread access message. Either way, the correct fix is to change the code so that the background thread only does background work, and access to UI elements is done only with the UI thread. You should try to use the `ProgressChanged` event to communicate from background to UI, but if you can't, then use `Control.Invoke()` to execute the code that accesses UI elements from the background thread.

Comment: Use _ProgressChanged to update UI - OR - wait until looping is done and use _RunWorkerCompleted. Do not allow the UI to change from the other thread you have created. You also may need to set ReportProgress = true;

Comment: SO questions should include the code that **doesn't** work.  Standard bug is to trigger a fire-hose bug, calling ReportProgress or Begin/Invoke() from the worker far too often.  The UI thread will be burning 100% core trying to keep up with the changes and will no longer take care of the lower-priority work, painting and responding to input.  A basic workaround to avoid flooding the user's eyes with irrelevant information he cannot possibly read fast enough and slowing down the worker intentionally with Thread.Sleep(30) in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't recommended to directly change parts of the UI from within a `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event, instead I recommend using `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` and editing the UI inside THAT method.

Here is an example of how I would implement changing a textbox's value to 'x':

```
public void searchForAll(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //Define background worker
   var MyBack = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
   for(...)
   {
     //Send some data to ReportProgress
     MyBack.ReportProgress(0, "any object of any form goes here");
   }
}
```

Then in the report progress method:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
}
```

Please note that you have to set `Backgroundworker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;` otherwise the worker won't be able to report the progress.